# XWPF POI Border Left Paragraph follow text position

Tags: apache-poi, border, indentation, paragraph, xwpf

How to change Border Left Paragraph, but the border follow text position, example if text indent so the border will indent too. Or text format bullet and number, the border will follow second line too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6EZM.jpg)

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm93D.jpg)

Comment: Please update your picture to show show all paragraph marks in current Word document by Home > **π** Show/Hide button. So we can see how this is achieved in Word.

Comment: i update picture...please check...

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you see a paragraph mark ¶ in Word document view in Word GUI a paragraph ends and a new one starts. So all your red left border lines are left border lines of different single paragraphs.

So what you see is the same as in following complete example:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class CreateWordParagraphBordersAndIndent {
    
 static String cTAbstractNumDecimalXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"1\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2.%3\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";
    
 private static BigInteger createNumbering(XWPFDocument document, String abstractNumXML) throws Exception {
  CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(abstractNumXML);
  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);
  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);
  return numID;
 }
    
 private static void setBorderLeftColor(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String rgb) {
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() == null) return; // no paragraph properties = no borders
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr() == null) return; // no paragraph border 
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr().getLeft() == null) return; // no left border
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr().getLeft().setColor(rgb);
 }
 
 private static void setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(double tabStopPosInInches, XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().getTabArray(0).setVal(
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.LEFT);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().getTabArray(0).setLeader(
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabTlc.HYPHEN);
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().getTabArray(0).setPos(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(tabStopPosInInches * 1440))); 
 }
 
 private static void setPageSize(XWPFDocument document, double widthInInches, double heightInInches, double leftPageMarginInInches, double rightPageMarginInInches) {
  if (document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr() == null) document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  if (document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz() == null) document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewPgSz();
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz().setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(widthInInches * 1440)));
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgSz().setH(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(heightInInches * 1440)));
  if (document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar() == null) document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewPgMar();
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setLeft(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(leftPageMarginInInches * 1440)));
  document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().getPgMar().setRight(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(rightPageMarginInInches * 1440))); 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  BigInteger numIDDecimalList = createNumbering(document, cTAbstractNumDecimalXML);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The text:");
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH); // alingment justify
  // set tab stop at position 6.5 inches 
  // (right page margin for page size letter and 1 inch left and right page margin)
  setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line.");
  run.addTab();
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH); // alingment justify
  setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
  paragraph.setIndentationLeft((int)Math.round(0.5 * 1440));
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. Additional this paragraph is left indented. This is justify aligned paragraph having fill characters (leaders) up to tab stop in last line. Additional this paragraph is left indented.");
  run.addTab();

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numIDDecimalList);
  paragraph.setNumILvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
  setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is a numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines. This is a numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines.");
  run.addTab();
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setNumID(numIDDecimalList);
  paragraph.setNumILvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
  setTabStopLeaderHYPHEN(6.5, paragraph);
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);
  setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is another numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines. This is another numbered paragraph which is long enough to go over multiple lines.");
  run.addTab();
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("End of example.");
  
  // set page size letter format (8.5 x 11 inches) and 1 inch left and right page margin
  setPageSize(document, 8.5, 11d, 1d, 1d);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordParagraphBordersAndIndent.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

So no magic anywhere.

The appearance of the numbered texts in your picture is a misusing of word processing. There the first line of the numbered text is in a separate paragraph. And the following paragraph is set left indented as much that it stands correct. But that should not be so. The text which is numbered belongs together. That's why it also should be in one paragraph. Then the indention also is correct automatically. One should not misusing word processing by inserting not correct paragraph breaks.

Comment: thats ok, but how to solve bullet and numbering, which the line position was indent in second line.

Comment: in bullet and numbering, the line left border, in not first line are indent.  please check again the picture focus in bullet and number.

Comment: @Eko: As said, then first line of the numbered text would must be in a separate paragraph. And the following paragraph would must get left indented as much that it stands correct. But that should not be so. The text which is numbered belongs together. That's why it also should be in one paragraph. Then the indention also is correct automatically. So I will not misusing word processing by inserting not correct paragraph breaks. But you may do what you mean to need to do.

Comment: plese check image was i update.....green circle